# Excel: Pivot chart of values using value-stdDev as error bars?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, pivot-chart

> I have a table of measurements, with each data point being measured multiple times. 
>   I would like to create a PivotChart which displays the
>   average value and uses the value's standard deviation as error-bars.

This is what I have so far:

[image: EXCEL Sheet]

- My DataTable has one category column (Date & Time) and one value column.
- I have a PivotTable which generates me the average value, and it also generates the standard deviation
- My chart currently shows the average and the stdDev as individual data series.

I would like to have the stdDev series (orange) *not* in the graph, but have the average series (blue) to show error bars. These error bars should have the size of the stdDev values.

I can find the error-bar option, but I don't see a way to assign the (computed) StdDev as magnitude.

The options given, only use the standard deviation *across the values of the pivotTable*.

[image: Not what I want]

**This is *not* what I want.**

But if I go to the advanced options:

[image: Options]

I can also only find a method to specify a *fixed* custom value.

[image]

While the field seems to allow for a table-range to be selected, I can only do so for a *specific* section. i.e. I can select the according values in the pivot table and get my graph:

[image: Solution, but not quite]

The error-bars are now as I want them, but any change of the pivot table structure, i.e. adding new dates, looses the connection:

[image: No]

I want the error-bars to always use the computed value of the same row - can this be done?

( And I also want to hide the orange series, but that is secondary. )

Answer (score 1):

Using VBA, I would create an *event* which fires whenever anything in the pivot chart gets updated. In this event I would write code which fills in the correct cell references for error bars. So, whenever the pivot chart gets updated, error bar references get updated too.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
  Dim rng As Range
  Set rng = Me.PivotTables("PivotTable1").DataBodyRange.PivotField.DataRange.Offset(, 1)
  With Me.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(1)
    .HasErrorBars = True
    .ErrorBar Direction:=xlY, Include:=xlBoth, _
              Type:=xlErrorBarTypeCustom, _
              Amount:=rng, _
              MinusValues:=rng
  End With

End Sub
```

<sup>You may have to change pivot name `"PivotTable1"` and the chart name `"Chart 1"` to the actual names in your sheet.</sup>

This code must be put inside the corresponding sheet module in VBA editor, which can be opened with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>.

Comment: Really clever solution, I'll have to give it a try. However, one would think that such a straight-forward requirement would be something already implemented in Excel on a more user-friendly basis! (After all, it would only be a single "add" to the existing options...)

Comment: Well, this is Microsoft :) I am not surprised anymore when I see lack of basic features and quality assurance on *slightly* more advanced things than just plotting a recommended chart.